# Light-oauth hazelcast purpose

Tags: oauth-2.0, light-4j

I've took a look on documentation.

I don't quite figure out how hazelcast is used.
I mean, I've look up on docker-like files, but I don't find any deployment of hazelcast.

Which services make use of hazelcast?

By other side, why do you use an imDg (hazelcast) and persistent sql-like databases?

What are you storing in hazelcast, and what are you storing at mysql (or any sql-like database)?

Answer (score 0):

The light-oauth2 is implemented with 7 microservices and the Hazelcast is used to share the data between these services and shield the database layer so that you can use any database as these real services don't have any knowledge about the underline database. All database related code is encapsulated in the cache module and it is easy to be customized.

By default, the Hazelcast is embedded so it is transparent to the users. If you deploy the services to multiple VMs, make sure to open the port for the Hazelcast. If you deploy the services to the Openshift or Kubernetes cluster, we have some example deployment configuration available at

https://github.com/networknt/light-config-test/tree/master/light-oauth2